In which circumstances is the integral of a quasiconvex function again quasiconvex?
Let $X$ be a convex subset of a real vector space and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a quasiconvex function, that is, $f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2) \leq \max(f(x_1), f(x_2))$ for $\lambda \in[0,1]$.
Now consider the mapping
$$ h\mapsto \int_X f(h(x)) d\mu(x)$$
with $\mu$ a finite measure.
The answer of the question Integral of Quasi-concave function is Quasi-concave has already given a counter-example that in general, this mapping is not quasiconvex again. My question is, however, if there are assumptions on $f$, $X$ or $\mu$ that can make this mapping quasiconvex? Obviously I do not want to relax the quasiconvexity of $f$ to convexity though. For instance, would strict quasiconvexity of $f$ do, or maybe monotonicity or some other assumption?

What is the domain  of the map $h\mapsto \int_X f\circ h,d\mu$? it seems to me that your map is not well defined as $f\circ h$ may not be integrable.

So i think $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or what do you mean?

And the integral can probably take values in $[-\infty, \infty]$

The problem is worst that what you propose. For example, $f(x)=x$ is quasi-convex (also quasi-concave) on $[-1,1]$. Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure in $[-1,1]$.  The function $f(x)=x$ is quasi-convex (also quasi-convae). Let $h(x)=\frac1x$ for $x\neq0$ and $0$ otherwise. $int_{[-1,1]}f\circ h dm$ is not defined. Some additional restrictions on $f$ are needed to make sense of $\Phi(h)=\int_X f\circ g,d\mu$

I thinks that the closest type of objects to what you are looking for at the so called Orlicz spaces. Here is a posting about them. There is a cost amount of literature on them.

Thank you for your suggestion! So are Orlicz spaces a special case of Lp spaces?

And the restrictions we need on f to make the integral well defined, will these restrictions also make the whole mapping quasiconvex?

It is actually the other way around: $L_p$ spaces, $1\leq p<\infty$ are special cases of Orlicz spaces ($\Phi(t)=t^p$).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
